# UWP - LinearGradientBrush turns transparents UIelements on foreground

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have following XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
                    <Border Width="100" Height="100">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="-10,10" EndPoint="10,0" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
                                <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="4"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="Red"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>

                    </Border>
                    <Polyline Points="0,0 10,10 50,10 90,60" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4"/>
                </Canvas>
                <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
                    <Border Width="100" Height="100">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="-10,10" EndPoint="10,0" 
                                                 SpreadMethod="Pad">
                                <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="4"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="Red"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>

                    </Border>
                    <Polyline Points="0,0 10,10 50,10 90,60" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4"/>
                </Canvas>
      </StackPanel>
```

and it looks like:

[image: object on foreground turns transparent]

When I put SpreadMethod="Repeat" on a LinearGradientBrush, it makes all UIelements over the brush, half-transparent. Is this a bug?, how can I fix this?

(It is more weird, if I give the polyline a fill color, it's stroke gets hard black)

Both target and min versions of the project are Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0; build 16299). IDE is VS2017.

Comment: I could reproduce this issue on windows build 16299, but when I test it on windows 10 RS4(17134), it worked well. Please try it on OS 17134.

Comment: Thank you comrade. So, it do is a bug. Will try on OS17134.

Comment: Have you tried it on OS 17134?

Comment: not yet, switched to other tasks in development